# How Do I Plot Histograms and Binomial Distributions Side by Side?

Tags: plotting, graphics

Here is the code I thought might yield up two histograms and two binomial distributions plotted side by side:

```
Show[Histogram[dataA, {-0.5, 6.5, 1}, "PDF"], 
 Histogram[dataC, {4.5, 12.5, 1}, "PDF"], 
 DiscretePlot[PDF[BinomialDistribution[6, 0.5], x], {x, 0, 7}, 
  PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]], 
 DiscretePlot[PDF[BinomialDistribution[7, 0.65], x - 5], {x, 5, 13}, 
  PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]]]
```

No workee! I get the first Histogram and the first Binomial. But, unfortunately, the image terminates at a value of around 7.25.

Answer (score 2):

```
dataA = RandomVariate[BinomialDistribution[6, 0.5], 100];
dataC = RandomVariate[BinomialDistribution[7, 0.65], 100] + 5;
Show[Histogram[Evaluate[{dataA, dataC}], {-0.5, 13, 1}, "PDF"], 
DiscretePlot[PDF[BinomialDistribution[6, 0.5], x], {x, 0, 7}, 
PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]], 
DiscretePlot[PDF[BinomialDistribution[7, 0.65], x - 5], {x, 5, 13}, 
PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Mister PatoCriollo: Thanks a bunch. That's exactly what I was looking for. @PatoCriollo